# Run-time error R6034 when compiling from the command prompt

Tags: c, mingw, runtime-error

I tried to compile a simple "hello world" program in C (using `MinGW`) from the command prompt and had the following error:

> R6034 : An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I've done a couple searches on the subject and there seems to be a consensus on stray `mscvr` files placed in the path variable by other programs.

I've downloaded Process Explorer and tried to find any such files, but  the `msvcr` files that I find (`msvcr80` and `msvcrt`) are all loaded from the system32 folder.

This is what I have in my system path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32;c:\mingw\bin.
```

Any help on how to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Msvcr80.dll should *not* be present in c:\windows\system32.  It can only live in the side-by-side cache, c:\windows\winsxs directory.  Remove that DLL.  It is otherwise *very* unclear how a "hello world" program could have a dependency on it.

Comment: thanks. I finally figured out what was wrong. Matlab was the culprit; taking it out of my path solved the problem! :)

Comment: Perhaps you should convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what was wrong. Matlab was the culprit; taking it out of my path solved the problem! :) – Dave